# Can this answer be salvaged?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

This answer ([link for users of 2k+ reputation](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/7837/102)) has been flagged as rude/abusive and **deleted and locked.**

[image: Screenshot of answer]

I believe the rude/abusive part can be edited out without needing the rude/abusive part. The answer overall gives a helpful insight on the reasoning.

This also serves as reminder that if you believe a post is rude/abusive in one section, you can edit and remove that part. If the answerer is persistent and reverted your removal, you can flag it for rude/abusive.

**Should we unlock, remove the rude examples, and undelete it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll say no, for the sole reason that if you remove the rude/abusive parts, there's nothing left. I'm going to talk about this even while leaving context about this user out of it.

The first two paragraphs seem . . . fine. They're just talking about legal aspects (which I am not familiar with, and so cannot judge based on correctness). It's talking about the law in France, which is the country to OP is interested in, so it's relevant.

After that, the post becomes rude. It . . .

- Mocks the situation and issues surrounding gender.
- Suggests mocking the person taking the photo, and "getting a laugh" at their expense.
- Suggests making sexual remarks, which are likely to get the OP in trouble.
- Refers to much of the rest of the world as "stuck up countries".

[We've talked before about editing out rude content](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1940/102), and I know that I can speak for others when I say that I appreciate the thought here. But if you edit out all of the offensive remarks . . . there's nothing left of this answer besides two paragraphs of legal commentary, which don't answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

## No.

We've been editing out the rude portions for many of their posts. We are tired doing it again and again. Said user is not showing any signs of improving their way of writing. Either they should start writing better or just don't write any.

Comment: +1 - Sometimes rude, sometimes cynically minded/worded and leading to a possible *rude reading version*, I (too) find their interventions/measures being (often) *on the edge*. I don't know if it's a personality trait or someone who like to provoque (for fun?), but still....

Comment: Flagging and deletion are standard, legitimate and necessary community responses when a post is rude or abusive. And some members apparently believe in writing posts 'on the edge'... Be that as it may, what I appreciate is that user *peufeu* is a committed member who has posted 60 answers here (many of which are very good answers) and has collected 4000+ reputation, @ NVZ and @OldPadawan.

Comment: @EnglishStudent While I understand your concern, you should know that I've seen things you may have missed. If you see 4000 for peufue, it's the part remaining after hundreds of their rep were removed for their controversial answers. I am in support of editing and improving things. I am a good editor myself I think. What I don't like is the same user making it our job to clean up after them.

Comment: I am also not advocating editing their answers @NVZ. That's why I said *"Flagging and deletion are standard, legitimate and necessary community responses when a post is rude or abusive.*" If the member writes any more rude/abusive answers they too should not be edited but flagged and deleted. My point is however that a member who does not care about IPS is not going to write 60 answers and collect 4000+ reputation. Putting a spin on what we Indians often say, [***he is like that only!***](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=indians+we+are+like+that+only+-book)

Comment: You should never have edited abusive posts in the first place. That's what flags are for. It's easy not to get tired doing when you flag instead of edit ;)

Comment: @curiousdannii I never edit abusive posts. I just flag and delete them. I saw "we" here, on behalf of others who do edit.

Comment: Then who is your answer speaking for? Let them speak for themselves and their own questionable actions if you're not one of them.

Comment: @curiousdannii Is there a rule like that?

Comment: Not a strict rule. But if you don't do it then it's not very honest to say you're tired of it, and if you don't believe in it then you can't defend it as a good course of action.

Comment: @curiousdannii I do feel strongly about it. I have argued with those editors about it. I am tired seeing their time wasted helping an abusive user multiple times and the user does not change their ways. So I don't see why my answer is poor in that sense. :)

Comment: Fair enough! I'd be tired on their behalf too if I had known it was a common occurrence here.

Comment: @curiousdannii Think of not allowing a bad person into your home, even when your home is technically your parents', and you're acting on behalf of the kind and caring parents who don't grow tired of welcoming in the said person. Some analogy, I suppose it is.